# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) LARAVEL 5 and AJAX

Tags: laravel-5.1

When I want use Ajax to update article in console I got: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)"

my jQuery code:

```
setInterval(function()
{
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();

    var url        = window.location.href;
    var article_id = /id\.([\d]+)/.exec(url)[1];

    $.ajax(
    {   
        url: '//' + $(location).attr('host') + '/cms/article/addDraft/' + article_id, 
        type: 'POST', 
        data: new FormData($('form.formAjax')[0]),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(response)
        {
            var alert = 'alert alert-warning';

            $('.alert-box')
            .hide()
            .addClass(alert)
            .html(response)
            .slideDown(1500);
            setTimeout(function() { $('.alert-box').slideUp(1500) }, 600);
        }
    });
},
6000);
```

and php:

```
// ADD ARTICLE DRAFT
public function addDraft($article_id)
{
    Articles::where('id', '=', $article_id)->update(['title'       => Request::Input('title'),
                                                     'description' => Request::Input('description')]);

    return response(trans('errors.positive'), 200);
}
```

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

look in your routes.php file.
Your POST request has to corespond with Route::post(), not with Route::get().